# Comparator. How to sort by age, but if name is "A", move it to the end of list?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, comparator

I have the next task:

I have object MyObject:

```
MyObject {
  private String name;
  private int age;
}
```

Using the Comparator compare() method implementation, I have to sort the list of MyObject by age, but if the name of MyObject is "A", this element should be moved to the end of the list. The list shouldn't contain 2 elements with "A" name, so we ignore this case.

I've written the next code, but it doesn't work

```
@Override
public int compare(MyObject myObject, MyObject t1) {
if (myObject.getName().equals("A")) {
  return 1;
}else if (myObject.getAge() == t1.getAge()) {
  return 0;
} else if (myObject.getAge() > t1.getAge()) {
  return 1;
} else {
  return -1;
}
}
```

Actually I don't surprised that it doesn't work, as I don't understand which sorting algorithm is used in this case.

Comment: In your compare method you always have to compare both objects with each other. In your first if statement you are only looking at one object and checking if it contains A and then return 1 if that's the case. You need to compare both objects and implement the comparing logic according to the method contract: -> If both objects names are "A" you need to return 0 because they are equal, if one has the name "A" and the other doesn't you need to return +1/-1 respectively.

Comment: Thanks, I understand what are you talking about, but I have no idea how to implement that correct. Thanks for the advice, I'll try to do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like:

```
@Override
public int compare(MyObject m1, MyObject m2) {
   if (m1.getName().equals("A") && !m2.getName().equals("A")) {
      return 1;
   }else if (!m1.getName().equals("A") && m2.getName().equals("A")) {
      return -1;
   } else {
      return Integer.compare(m1.getAge(), m2.getAge());
   }
}
```